# Creating SOAP WS in Java and get the request as a String

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I was wondering if it was actually possible to create a Java SOAP Webservice without using it's WSDL.

**Context:**

The idea is that I have to mock a webservice, so I have its WSDL. The mock will only read the soap request, search if there are any similar request (as key in a map) and send the matching response (as its value). This is for automated testing purpose. The problem is not the "map" part.

Anyway, I've been using Axis and eclipse to generate classes and files and load them in tomcat from the WSDL. So far it've been a mess, with a lot of compatibility issues between these components. And it's gonna be much more difficult to compare the input or serialize the output to do what I want this way.

I thought about creating a REST endpoint and send the soap request through it (so I would directly get the SOAP request !), but I rode somewhere that soap request weren't valid and wouldn't be retreived by the REST endpoint... Also, won't the client application throw an error if there is no WSDL at this address ?

**My question is:**

Is there a way to create an access point, that looks like a SOAP Webservice (from clients), but which allows me to get the full soap request (as a String for example) and send a response (still as a String) inside a Java app?

**Complements:**

I'm looking for something, a library, maybe just an annotation on Servlets, that doesn't needs (if possible) to generate a huge load of classes and xml files everywhere. The app would be running on tomcat (but I can be a basic Java app). Using maven and spring wouldn't be a problem.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, clients do not require an WSDL. But it is a nice feature - use a normal servlet and handle the "?WSDL" manually. Then use some simple XPath or parse logic to extract the payload as a DOM document.